# Cannot override the final method from ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm in the process of migrating from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBarCompat library that was introduced in [Google IO 2013](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) (I do this so I can use ActionBarDrawerToggle).

I have already sorted out all the necessary dependencies (AppCompat, latest support library...), fixed all the imports but now when I try to use ActionBarActivity's `onMenuItemSelected` I get an error.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    ...
}
```

Error:

> Cannot override the final method from ActionBarActivity

The original method from `ActionBarActivity` (inherited from `FragmentActivity`) is final. When I used ABS, this was working, now I can't override the method.

(MenuItem is of class `android.view.MenuItem` and not the compat version...)

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using `onMenuItemSelected` I used `onOptionsItemSelected` and the code compiled okay.

Can it be that `onMenuItemSelected` appears in the docs but not in the code ?

Comment: To answer your question: No, in `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` method `onMenuItemSelected` is in the code, but it is **final** method, and you can't `@Override` **final** methods.

Comment: sorry I mistyped there, and its to late to edit. Of course I meant `android.support.v7.ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: @Stigi you're right but it's odd, because using ABS I did override it and it is defined final there as well. Not sure what is it's purpose if not to override it...